# Ayuda con instancia de clase que contiene array de string

Tags: c#, array, string, clase

Hola tengo una clase con un array como variable:

```
    public string history;
    public string[] answers;
    public StoryNode[] nextNode;
    public bool isFinal = false;
```

Quiero crear una referencia en otra clase, como debo rellenar al array, he hecho algo asi pero me da error:

```
  GameplayManager.StoryNode historia_inicial = new GameplayManager.StoryNode("Historia 1", {"Answer1", "Answer2"}, new StoryNode["1", "2"], false);
```

Como relleno un array al instanciar otra clase? Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y asi ganar tu primera medalla. Tambien es interesante leer [ask] para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Necesitaríamos algo mas de información para poder ayudarte, como la definición de `StoryNode` y la de `GameplayManager.StoryNode`. Tambien que error es el que te da en el código que nos has enseñado.

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes una clase como ser

```
public class StoryNode 
{
    public StoryNode()
    {
        this.isFinal = false;
    }

    public string history {get;set;}
    public string[] answers {get;set;}
    public StoryNode[] nextNode {get;set;}
    public bool isFinal {get;set;}
}
```

entonces puedes asignar las proiedades

```
StoryNode historia_inicial = new StoryNode()
{
    history = "Historia 1",
    answers = new string[] {"Answer1", "Answer2"},
    nextNode = new StoryNode[] { new StoryNode(), new StoryNode()}
}
```

de esta forma al instanciar asignas los valores

Usa propeidades en la clase y no variables publicas

Veras que el array de string instancias y la asignacion define el numero de elementos.

Ahora bien el `nextNode` deberia verse como defines el constructor, porque no veo que asignando un numero funcione, deebs crear la instancias usando el `new`